# Prove that there exists a $d \times d$ unitary matrix $U$ which cannot be decomposed as a product of fewer than $d-1$ two-level unitary matrices

Tags: quantum-mechanics, homework-and-exercises, quantum-information, quantum-computer, unitarity

I'm trying to solve exercise 4.38 from Nielsen and Chuang, which asks to "*Prove that there exists a $d \times d$ unitary matrix $U$ which cannot be decomposed as a product of fewer than $d-1$ two-level unitary matrices*".

In this context, a *two-level* matrix is a matrix which acts nontrivially on at most two levels. In other words, we say that $A$ is a two-level matrix if it can be written as $A=\tilde A \oplus I$ for some $2\times2$ matrix $\tilde A$ (up to a rearrangement of the matrix components). This definition is found in section 4.5.1 in the 10th edition of the book.

If you find unitary matrices $U_{d-1}, U_{d-2}, \ldots, U_1$ such that the matrix $U_{d-1}U_{d-2}\ldots U_1U$ has a one in the top left-hand corner, all zeroes elsewhere in the first row and column, and the remaining $d-1 \times d-1$ submatrix (when you remove the first row and column) is *not* a two-level unitary, then the decomposition of $U$ must require more than $d-1$ two-level unitaries. That seems pretty clear, I'm just not sure where to go from here. Any hints/suggestions?

Comment: what is a "two-level unitary matrix"?

Comment: Doesn't this follow trivially by dimensionality reasons? $d^2>4(d-1)$, so you don't have enough degrees of freedom. Am I missing something?

Comment: @glS but that extra freedom is discrete, so it cannot affect the real dimension, right? I mean, I guess you are probably right, for otherwise the problem seems completely trivial. But I still cannot see it: if every $U$ could be expressed like that, then the manifold of all $U$'s is identical to the manifold of all $U$'s that can be expressed like that. But the former is of dimension $d^2$ (the number of continuous coordinates needed to specify an arbitrary element), while the latter is of dimension $4(d-1)$. So these manifolds cannot possibly be equal. I'm sure I'm missing something though...

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Suppose $U$ is a $d\times d$ unitary matrix which *can* be decomposed using less than $d-1$ two-level unitaries.

We can think of each two-level unitary as an "edge" *linking* some pair of modes, interpreting each mode as a vertex. Let us then ask what kinds of configurations can be obtained using less than $d-1$ edges. In other words, what kinds of graphs are possible using less than $d-1$ edges.

As discussed in [this math.SE post](https://math.stackexchange.com/a/4027846/173147), any such graph must contain *at least* two connected components. This means that there must be at least two subsets of vertices/modes, call them $V_1$ and $V_2$, which are *not* connected by any edge.

Physically, we can understand this as saying that if less than $d-1$ two-level unitaries are used to decompose $U$, then there must be two subsets of modes on which $U$ acts independently.
Upon rearranging the order of the levels, this means that $U=U_1\oplus U_2$ for some unitaries $U_1,U_2$.

In other words, *if $U$ can be built with less than $d-1$ two-level unitaries, then $U$ is block-diagonal in the computational basis*. Clearly not every $U$ has this form. To name one example, the [QFT](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Quantum_Fourier_transform) matrix doesn't.

To also verify this numerically, here's a Mathematica snippet that combines together $d-2$ random two-level unitaries and shows the resulting matrix. Consistently with the reasoning above, we can notice that any resulting matrix has a block-diagonal form:

```
d = 5;
numberTwoLevelUnitaries = d - 2;
randomTwoLevelUnitaries = Table[RandomUnitary@2, numberTwoLevelUnitaries];
randomPositions = Table[RandomSample[Range@d, 2], numberTwoLevelUnitaries] // Echo;
embeddedRandomUnitaries = Table[
  With[{pos = posAndUnitary[[1]], u = posAndUnitary[[2]]},
    ArrayFlatten[{
      {u, 0}, {0, IdentityMatrix[d - 2]}
    }] // ReplacePart[IdentityMatrix@d,
      Table[
        {pos[[i]], pos[[j]]} -> #[[i, j]],
        {i, 2}, {j, 2}
      ] // Flatten[#, 1] &
    ] &
  ],
  {posAndUnitary, Thread@{randomPositions, randomTwoLevelUnitaries}}
];
overallUnitary = Dot @@ embeddedRandomUnitaries;
overallUnitary // MatrixForm // Chop
```

Comment: Could you edit the question as to clarify what a "two-level unitary matrix" is? This is entirely unclear.  Thanks.

Comment: @NorbertSchuch to be fair, it's the notation also used in N&C, but yes I added it to the question for better clarity

Comment: To be fair, questions of the form "could you please explain the following problem from NC to me", without even quoting the necessary (non-standard, even for people with QI background!) questions are OT here.  I acknowledge the question displays some own thoughts, and I wouldn't vote to close it as HW, but I think it was clearly lacking details if it cannot be understood without opening NC.  Thanks for adding the information!

Comment: But now (after reading your addition) I am rather confused: Doesn't this follow simply by parameter counting? I mean, a dxd unitary has d^2 real parameters, and the 2-level unitaries have 4 real parameters each.  So you need *at least* O(d^2) of them to realize a general unitary.  Do I miss something?

Comment: In any case, Reck and Zeilinger (PRL '94?) is the reference for this decomposition :-)

Comment: @NorbertSchuch that's pretty much the comment also given to the question. I think the parameter counting argument assumes fixed positions for the unitaries in the decomposition. One should also take into account the discrete freedom in choosing their disposition. Granted, such additional discrete degrees of freedom don't affect the dimensionality argument, which still works fine. That's probably also the simple argument that N&C thought for the exercise. I just like the one in this answer better because it explicitly characterises the structure of the unitaries possible with such constructions

Comment: for example, following the result mentioned in the linked answer, that a graph $(V,E)$ contains at least $|V|-|E|$ connected components, one can generalise this result and infer that using at most $n$ two-level unitaries results in a matrix which can be decomposed as direct sum of at least $d-n$ submatrices

Comment: I have to admit I didn't fully go through the answer, but I agree that this gives an understanding of the structure one can achieve.  But I don't buy that the discrete degree of freedom gives a complication (I guess you say you agree); this would be like saying that having $\mathbb R$ and $i\mathbb R$, i.e. reals with a discrete degree of freedom, would give all complex numbers. --- Without further reason to do otherwise, I'd certainly always plead for the simplest argument. In particular, counting arguments can be used to shoot down *lots* of things easily, so one should encourage using them!

Comment: @NorbertSchuch This actually goes back to  Murnaghan FD. The unitary and rotation groups. Spartan books; 1962.  Reck supplied the optical implementation.

Comment: @ZeroTheHero Good to know. Interestingly, I think I know the Reck et al. reference from the Barenco et al. paper, where they use their construction to show that any unitary can be implemented with a certain gate set, so in retrospect it would have been more natural to refer to one of the original works which right away decompose unitaries, rather than studying gates in photonic setups and translate it back to unitary gates.

Comment: @NorbertSchuch see also W. R. Clements, P. C. Humphreys, B. J. Metcalf, W. S. Kolthammer, and I. A. Walmsley, “Optimal design for universal multiport interferometers,” Optica 3, 1460–1465 (2016) or de Guise, H., Di Matteo, O. and Sánchez-Soto, L.L., 2018. Simple factorization of unitary transformations. Physical review A, 97(2), p.022328 for different factorizations.  The Clements scheme is quite ingenious from an implementation perspective.